# ASP.NET MVC6 View Location Expander : How to add every views under a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a files's structure that can evolve in a way that we don't know exactly where the views will be located.

Here is a example :

- /UI

  - /Home

    - /App

      - /Another

        - /...
        - /AnotherController.cs
        - /AnotherComponent.js
        - /AnotherCompoent.cshtml
      - /AppController.cs
      - /AppComponent.js
      - /AppCompoent.cshtml
    - /HomeController.cs
    - /Index.cshtml

Add each of the options in the `ViewLocationExpander` becomes hard to read and hard to maintain very quickly.

```cs
public class CustomViewLocationExpander: IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        return new[] {  
            "~/UI/{1}/{0}.cshtml",  
            "~/UI/Shared/{0}.cshtml",  
            "~/UI/Home/App/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/UI/Home/App/Another/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/UI/Admin/App/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/UI/Admin/App/Another/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
            // ...
        };
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context) { }
}
```

Is there a syntax to **add every view under a directory** in a **secure way**?
Like `"~UI/**/{1}/{0}.cshtml"` for example?